# Is this the correct definition of a "corpus"?

Tags: nlp, computer-science, nltk

I have a huge string of raw text that is about 200,000 words long. It's a book.

I want to use these words to analyze the word relationships, so that I can apply those relationships to other applications.

Is this called a "corpus"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *corpus*, in linguistics, is any coherent body of real-life(*) text or speech being studied. So yes, a book is a corpus. The fact that it's in one string doesn't matter, as long as you don't randomly shuffle the characters.

(*) As opposed to a bunch of made up phrases being shown to test subjects to measure their responses, as is commonly done in psycholinguistics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus
Specifically, because it's uses for *statistics*.

Answer (score 0):

Usually "corpus" is used to refer to a structured collection, but linguists would know what you're talking about.